# At what length scales do classical calculations break down and quantum corrections become relevant?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hydrogen

So I have been tasked to determine at what precise length the classical calculations of the hydrogen atom break down.

I'll explain - the Coulomb interaction between the nucleus and the electron in the atom is a classical interaction, predicting that at some point the two will collide. Quantum mechanically this is not the case, the Coulomb interaction, to my understanding, is counter-acted by the Heisenberg uncertainty principle.

If somebody can explain this to me or even show it mathematically, I would appreciate it!

Comment: Quantum mechanical behavior is not a matter of scale. There simply is no classical world at all. The mere existence of stable matter is a quantum mechanical effect. That the uncertainty principle is responsible for quantum mechanics is a popular but false explanation. The uncertainty principle is merely a fairly trivial mathematical lemma about linear operators. It shows up whenever a Fourier transform comes into play (but that's just a special case of it).